# Chown not working

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, chown

On Ubuntu 12.04, the chown command doesn't seem to be working like it should

> root@server:/var/www/folder/# ls -al

Running this puts out

> drwxr-xr-x 11  776 sftponly 4096 Feb 17 14:08 Other_Folder

I need write permissions for the group, so I run:

> chown -R 776 ./Other_Folder

Then when I run ls -al again, the output is still

> drwxr-xr-x 11  776 sftponly 4096 Feb 17 14:08 Other_Folder

Comment: which fs do you have?

Comment: chown g+w ./Other_Folder

Comment: fs wise, we're using ext4

Comment: chmod g+w ./Other_Folder did the trick, thanks guys!

Comment: chmod also knows the -R, if you need that recursive.

Comment: Afaik your question had a better place  on http://unix.stackexchange.com .

Comment: The problem might be the FILESYSTEM for instance, ntfs

Answer (score 35):

`chown` is used to change ownership of the file, not change permissions.

`ls -al` is not showing you who owns the file, just its permissions.

If root owns those files, you'll need to `chown` them properly, before you can change their permissions:

```
chown -R yourname:yourname folderName
```

Then as the owner you can change their permissions:

```
chmod -R 776 folderName
```

**Edit:** 
I double checked the syntax and it seems to be right, you'll likely need to use sudo to use them.

Comment: Use chown -R carefully! Some folders may contain files that need to belong to root!

Comment: -l does show you the owner I think; from `info ls`: If the -l option is given, the following information is displayed for
     each file: file mode, number of links, owner name, group name, number of
     bytes in the file, abbreviated month, day-of-month file was last modi-
     fied, hour file last modified, minute file last modified, and the path-
     name

Comment: permission denied :( when chmodding.